# Calling AWS Lambda via api gateway on localstack doesn't work as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, localstack

Hi I have downloaded the most basic java lambda example

```
package helloworld;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent;

/**
 * Handler for requests to Lambda function.
 */
public class App implements RequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent> {

    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(final APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent input, final Context context) {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.put("X-Custom-Header", "application/json");

        APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent response = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent()
                .withHeaders(headers);
        try {
            final String pageContents = this.getPageContents("https://checkip.amazonaws.com");
            String output = String.format("{ \"message\": \"hello world\", \"location\": \"%s\" }", pageContents);

            return response
                    .withStatusCode(200)
                    .withBody(output);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return response
                    .withBody("{}")
                    .withStatusCode(500);
        }
    }

    private String getPageContents(String address) throws IOException{
        URL url = new URL(address);
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()))) {
            return br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        }
    }
}
```

I then create a docker image with commands

```
mvn compile dependency:copy-dependencies -DincludeScope=runtime
docker build -t $DOCKER_TAG .
docker push $DOCKER_TAG
```

From then I have the following terraforms files

```
# Create the lambda role (using lambdarole.json file)
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role" {
  name               = "${var.stack_prefix}-role-lambdarole-${var.unique_name}"
  assume_role_policy = file("${path.module}/files/lambdarole.json")
}

# Apply the Policy Document we just created
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "lambda_policy" {
  name   = "${var.stack_prefix}-role-lambdapolicy-${var.unique_name}"
  role   = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.id
  policy = file("${path.module}/files/lambdapolicy.json")
}

#  Variables
variable "apiName" { default = "java-lambda" }

# API Gateway
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  function_name = "${var.apiName}"
  image_uri     = "localhost:4510/ac.uk-jlambda:1.0.0"
  role          = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn
  runtime       = "java11"
  handler       = "example.FunctionConfiguration::Function"
  timeout       = "60"
  publish       = true
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "apiLambda" {
  name = "${var.apiName}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "proxy" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "{proxy+}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "proxyMethod" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.proxy.id
  http_method   = "ANY"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambda" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_method.proxyMethod.resource_id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.proxyMethod.http_method

  integration_http_method = "GET"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.invoke_arn
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "proxy_root" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.root_resource_id
  http_method   = "ANY"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambda_root" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_method.proxy_root.resource_id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.proxy_root.http_method

  integration_http_method = "GET"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.invoke_arn
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "apideploy" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda,
    aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda_root,
  ]

  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
  stage_name  = "test"
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw" {
  statement_id  = "AllowAPIGatewayInvoke"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

  # The "/*/*" portion grants access from any method on any resource
  # within the API Gateway REST API.
  source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.execution_arn}/*/*"
}

output "base_url" {
  value = aws_api_gateway_deployment.apideploy.invoke_url
}
```

Then I call terraform init, plan and apply.
Afterwards when I use the command:

```
awslocal --region=eu-west-2 lambda invoke --function-name java-lambda --payload '{"key1":"hello world!","key2":"hello another world!"}' --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out /dev/stdout
```

I get output

```
{"body":"{\"message\": \"Go Serverless v2.0! Your function executed successfully!\", \"input\": {\"key1\": \"hello world!\", \"key2\": \"hello another world!\"}}","statusCode":200}
{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "LogResult": "",
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}
```

Then I use this command to find the id of the api gateway

```
awslocal apigateway get-rest-apis --region eu-west-2
```

and use this id in the following url format

```
http://localhost:4566/restapis/ngabak60o4/test/_user_request_/
```

This shows a json response in the browser

```
{
message: "Go Serverless v2.0! Your function executed successfully!",
input: {
body: "",
headers: {
Authorization: "",
Cache-Control: "max-age=0",
Connection: "keep-alive",
Cookie: "aekt_hostname=ucl-3.ombiel.co.uk; a=96df33c3b846ea04YD9uLTvub3R3%2FxtuaEssxWBymFrbu7Vg5LH%2BpWGOQJvXpE9FywQ4OnoISm8ccMID0yeoi1EnhlDcau66bNXuh1k6PHi317kCOJr3%2B7Qus8vEYkw%2FCs7fwS%2Bmd5%2B7ZvwveqgUgTtYbdlsw1Jn6ozcbDbmw3oqhXt1r3%2Fi%2F9A5I3P9gHHYwyfXjLMHWjqZFmYJ7elQCSgTCPeSkuQW%2BbRGNw3XfqSuCvd8%2BEjQCqApjQ9C3Yb3RX9DcueKaIfjntKCXbxyyyhgdNCI7bYoQuqAOdZpmZs0pygabE%2B1GuDfRTbkJ%2BbLRaSL8eYjUAmrzfKP; __a=471ffc53886568546223239137b5ac60; ombl_web2=yes; ombl_device_grade=med; campusM[7]=8%5B; __utmz=111872281.1650902813.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utma=111872281.1289308641.1650902813.1652888907.1655293849.25",
Host: "localhost:4566",
Remote-Addr: "172.17.0.1",
Sec-Ch-Ua: "" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="102", "Google Chrome";v="102"",
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: "?0",
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: ""Windows"",
Sec-Fetch-Dest: "document",
Sec-Fetch-Mode: "navigate",
Sec-Fetch-Site: "none",
Sec-Fetch-User: "?1",
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: "1",
User-Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
X-Forwarded-For: "172.17.0.1, localhost:4566, 127.0.0.1, localhost:4566",
accept: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
accept-encoding: "gzip, deflate, br",
accept-language: "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
x-localstack-edge: "http://localhost:4566",
x-localstack-tgt-api: "apigateway"
},
httpMethod: "GET",
isBase64Encoded: false,
multiValueHeaders: {
Authorization: [
""
],
Cache-Control: [
"max-age=0"
],
Connection: [
"keep-alive"
],
Cookie: [
"aekt_hostname=ucl-3.ombiel.co.uk; a=96df33c3b846ea04YD9uLTvub3R3%2FxtuaEssxWBymFrbu7Vg5LH%2BpWGOQJvXpE9FywQ4OnoISm8ccMID0yeoi1EnhlDcau66bNXuh1k6PHi317kCOJr3%2B7Qus8vEYkw%2FCs7fwS%2Bmd5%2B7ZvwveqgUgTtYbdlsw1Jn6ozcbDbmw3oqhXt1r3%2Fi%2F9A5I3P9gHHYwyfXjLMHWjqZFmYJ7elQCSgTCPeSkuQW%2BbRGNw3XfqSuCvd8%2BEjQCqApjQ9C3Yb3RX9DcueKaIfjntKCXbxyyyhgdNCI7bYoQuqAOdZpmZs0pygabE%2B1GuDfRTbkJ%2BbLRaSL8eYjUAmrzfKP; __a=471ffc53886568546223239137b5ac60; ombl_web2=yes; ombl_device_grade=med; campusM[7]=8%5B; __utmz=111872281.1650902813.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utma=111872281.1289308641.1650902813.1652888907.1655293849.25"
],
Host: [
"localhost:4566"
],
Remote-Addr: [
"172.17.0.1"
],
Sec-Ch-Ua: [
"" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="102", "Google Chrome";v="102""
],
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: [
"?0"
],
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: [
""Windows""
],
Sec-Fetch-Dest: [
"document"
],
Sec-Fetch-Mode: [
"navigate"
],
Sec-Fetch-Site: [
"none"
],
Sec-Fetch-User: [
"?1"
],
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: [
"1"
],
User-Agent: [
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
],
X-Forwarded-For: [
"172.17.0.1, localhost:4566, 127.0.0.1, localhost:4566"
],
accept: [
"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
],
accept-encoding: [
"gzip, deflate, br"
],
accept-language: [
"en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
],
x-localstack-edge: [
"http://localhost:4566"
],
x-localstack-tgt-api: [
"apigateway"
]
},
multiValueQueryStringParameters: null,
path: "/",
pathParameters: { },
queryStringParameters: null,
requestContext: {
accountId: "000000000000",
apiId: "kkjc44n3w7",
authorizer: { },
domainName: "localhost",
domainPrefix: "localhost",
httpMethod: "GET",
identity: {
accountId: "000000000000",
sourceIp: "127.0.0.1",
userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
},
path: "/test/",
protocol: "HTTP/1.1",
requestId: "81af5979-6221-407e-b1a0-6ea74e09fb96",
requestTime: "23/Jun/2022:13:00:09 +0000",
requestTimeEpoch: 1655989209451,
resourceId: "1gbuakz0ci",
resourcePath: "/",
stage: "test"
},
resource: "/"
}
}
```

Which claims to be success. But I don't see the output of my handleRequest method.

I follow a similar tutorial for node js and that works correctly.

Can anyone please see what I have done wrong here?

Many thanks